# Term for a multi-verb infinitive?

Tags: terminology

I understand that "to boldly go" is a split infinitive. Is there a term for a multi-verb infinitive, like "to divide and conquer"?

Comment: *"to divide and conquer"* is not a multi-verb infinitive: it is separate infinitives separated by a coordinating conjunction. There is no fixed term word for this.

Comment: 'To _make believe_'  and 'to _make do_' are multi-word-verb to-infinitives.

Comment: It's not a multi-word infinitival but a coordination of two verb phrases governed by "to": "To [divide and conquer]. See LPH's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the infinitive. It's simply a coordination of verbs, in this case plain infinitivals. Which can happen anywhere you find a verb, or verb phrase.

> We [divide [and conquer]].
>
> We are [dividing [and conquering]].
>
> They were [divided [and conquered]].
>
> No one thought the [divided [and conquered]] nation could recover.
>
> The plan is to [divide [and conquer]].

We can have a coordination of *to*-infinitivals as well.

> The plan is [to divide [and to conquer]].

The verbs in the given example are both equally marked by the subordinator *to*, and could even have an object that is object of both verbs.

> We plan [to [[divide [and conquer]] them]].

The *to* is not part of the verb, but rather a marker of subordination.

If a label is needed, a *to*-infinitival with a coordination in predicator (head verb) position would do the trick.